# Proof of Paley-Zygmund inequality (lower bound for upper tail of square-integrable random variables)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a square integrable r.v. $X$ satisfying $P(|X| > 0) > 0$, the goal is to show that 
$$ P(|X| \ge \lambda E[|X|]) \ge \frac{(1-\lambda)^2 E^2[|X|]}{E[X^2]} $$

My attempt so far:

Let $A = \{|X| \ge \lambda E[|X|]\}$, and $1_A$ the indicator for $A$. 
Applying Holder's inequality to $\int |X| \chi_A dP$ gives us 
$$ \left (\int |X|\cdot 1_A dP\right )^2 \le \int |X|^2 dP \int 1_A^2 dP = E[X^2]P(A)$$

so that

$$ P(A) \ge \frac{E^2[|X|\cdot 1_A]}{E[X^2]} $$

Then it would suffice to show that $E[|X|\cdot 1_A] \ge (1-\lambda)E[|X|]$, but I am not sure how to do this or if this is on track in general.

Thanks!

Edit:

As a hint to others who come upon this: We can always decompose$E[X] = E[1_A X] + E[1_{A^\complement}X]$. You can bound one of these terms by $\lambda E[X]$, and applying Cauchy-Schwarz (= Holders for p = q = 2) gives you the desired result, which is known as the Paley-Zygmund inequality.

Comment: For anyone who cares - after a bit of googling this is known as the Paley-Zygmund inequality. Should I delete this?

Comment: I think to keep it for learning experience is not bad.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= \mathbb E\left[X\mathsf 1_{\{X\leqslant \lambda\mathbb E[X]\}}\right] +\mathbb E\left[X\mathsf 1_{\{X> \lambda\mathbb E[X]\}}\right]\\
&\geqslant \lambda\mathbb E[X]+ \mathbb E[X^2]^{1/2}\mathbb P(X>\lambda\mathbb E[X])^{1/2}\\
&\implies  \mathbb P(X\geqslant \lambda\mathbb E[X])^{1/2}\mathbb E[X^2]^{1/2}\geqslant \mathbb E[X](1-\lambda)\\
&\quad \implies\mathbb P(X\geqslant\lambda\mathbb E[X])\geqslant(1-\lambda)^2\frac{\mathbb E[X]^2}{\mathbb E[X^2]}.
\end{align}

Comment: c.f. Paley, R. E. A. C. and A. Zygmund. 1932. “A Note on Analytic Functions in the Unit Circle.” Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society 28(3):266–72.